# Couldn't install an app on my ipad using iTunes which was purchased with a different apple id

Tags: ipad, app-store, itunes

The Question i am asking might be a basic but i really need more information as it helps me a lot.

I have developed an app (Ver 1.0) and placed it on appstore.Recently i have uploaded a new version (1.1) which got approved.When my user updated his app on his device he experienced a crash.

My user had a back up of the ipa's which he purchased using his apple id.He sent me both versions of the app.Hoping that i could find a crash report on my device if i nstall them on my ipad, i tried insatlling 1.0 on my ipad but itunes throws me an error

Error: **The app "xxx" was not installed on the ipad "My pad" because you are not authorized for it on this computer.**

Query:  Can't i install an app on my ipad purchased by other person by authorizing with my apple id and password.

What should i do to get the app installed on my ipad.I am not sure if the user wishes to share his apple Id credentails with me.

Plz help.

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to authorize any app downloaded from the iOS App Store using the same Apple ID with which the app was originally purchased.  Portions of the app may be encrypted with a key tied to that specific Apple ID, and thus the app is useless without that iTunes account authorization and login.

Instead, check your 1.0 and 1.1 versions out of your source code repository, and rebuild the 2 versions of the app for Ad Hoc Distribution to yourself.  If you use the same SDK and build settings, these apps should be identical to what you submitted to Apple.  Then install those in sequence on your test device using iTunes or OTA.  Or if you archived the app versions before submission, use those.

Comment: Tnx Mr for the reply.I have tried the same advised by you earlier and i didn't find any crashes on my device.But my user was experiencing a crash,with an anxiety or to know if there is anything i am missing i posted the question.Any way i would try to get the crash report from the user and investigate the issue.once again tnx for the reply...